# C# MVC5 View not recognizing namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, namespaces, asp.net-mvc-5

I have recently run on this problem. I have tried to add namespace to Views/web.config or on top of the view, but still occur on the problem, where View can't find the contents of namespace.

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvD8S.png)

Ofcorse it is not a big problem, but it is annoying to always write the full namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should try write another using that contains your Resources path?

Comment: Yes, thanks, this worked, now I understand why, because Resources is part of the namespace. It is not an object, so it should be treated like a namespace not a class of objects. Thanks.